# AttributeError: 'Vocab' object has no attribute 'stoi'

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, torchtext

Trying to run a training script, after resolving a few error messages I've come accross this one, Anyone know what is happening here?

```
Batch size > 1 not implemented! Falling back to batch_size = 1 ...
Building multi-modal model...
Loading model parameters.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "translate_mm.py", line 166, in <module>
    main()
  File "translate_mm.py", line 98, in main
    use_filter_pred=False)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Thesis/thesis_code/onmt/io/IO.py", line 198, in build_dataset
    use_filter_pred=use_filter_pred)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Thesis/thesis_code/onmt/io/TextDataset.py", line 75, in __init__
    out_examples = list(out_examples)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Thesis/thesis_code/onmt/io/TextDataset.py", line 69, in <genexpr>
    out_examples = (self._construct_example_fromlist(
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Thesis/thesis_code/onmt/io/TextDataset.py", line 68, in <genexpr>
    example_values = ([ex[k] for k in keys] for ex in examples_iter)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Thesis/thesis_code/onmt/io/TextDataset.py", line 265, in _dynamic_dict
    src_map = torch.LongTensor([src_vocab.stoi[w] for w in src])
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Thesis/thesis_code/onmt/io/TextDataset.py", line 265, in <listcomp>
    src_map = torch.LongTensor([src_vocab.stoi[w] for w in src])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1178, in __getattr__
    type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'Vocab' object has no attribute 'stoi'
```

which refers to

```
    def _dynamic_dict(self, examples_iter):
        for example in examples_iter:
            src = example["src"]
            src_vocab = torchtext.vocab.Vocab(Counter(src))
            self.src_vocabs.append(src_vocab)
            # Mapping source tokens to indices in the dynamic dict.
            src_map = torch.LongTensor([src_vocab.stoi[w] for w in src])
            example["src_map"] = src_map

            if "tgt" in example:
                tgt = example["tgt"]
                mask = torch.LongTensor(
                        [0] + [src_vocab.stoi[w] for w in tgt] + [0])
                example["alignment"] = mask
            yield example
```

Note: the original model was made with a much older version of torchtext, I am guessing the error is related to that, but I am simply too inexperienced to know for sure.

Anyone has an idea? Googling this provided no significant results.

regards,
U.

Comment: I'm not working with these, so I'm not sure, but the message says that your `src_vocab` object which is type `torchtext.vocab.Vocab` doesn't have an attribute `stoi`. Looking at the docs [here](https://pytorch.org/text/stable/vocab.html) I see there's a `get_stoi` method, maybe that's what you need.

Comment: I see, I will try to see if I can make sense out of the code I am using and the get_stoi method, thanks for your correspondence.

Comment: Yeah, it's `get_stoi()[w]`

Answer (score 3):

You must use `get_stoi()[w]`.This is for the newer version after removing the legacy. You also can use `get_itos()` which returns a list of elements.